# Gulp destination relative to source

Tags: sass, gulp

I am trying to parse all SCSS files in all folders, and I need them to be in relative destinations to the original file.

Here is the representation of folder structure I want (basically, scss files in scss folders need to be saved as css files in css folder next to the original scss folder) and rogue scss files (not in scss folder) should have css file saved in same destination as the scss file.

```
html
│   README.md
│
└───app_abc
│   │   index.php
│   │   something_else.php
│   │
│   └───styles
│       └───scss
│       │       _mixins.scss
│       │       layout.scss
│       │       content.scss
│       │
│       └───css
│               layout.css
│               content.css
│   
└───app_def
│   │   index.php
│   │   something_else.php
│   │   rogue.scss
│   │   rogue.css
│   │
│   └───styles
│       └───scss
│       │       _mixins.scss
│       │       layout.scss
│       │       content.scss
│       │
│       └───css
│               layout.css
│               content.css
└───app_ghi
    ...
```

I tried playing with it for hours yesterday and today, but to no avail. I can make it to create the CSS file in the same folder, but that's not what I want.

Here is my gulpfile.js (there is a lot of "debug" stuff in it).

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    path = require('path'),
    through = require('through2');


const debug = require('gulp-debug');


const sassFiles = './html/**/[^_]*.scss';

function parsePath() {
    return through.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
        console.log(file.base);
        console.log(file.cwd);
        console.log(file.path);
        console.log(file.name);
        console.log(path.relative(file.cwd, file.path));
        console.log(path.relative(path.join(file.cwd, file.base), file.path))
        console.log(path.relative(path.join(file.cwd, file.base), file.path).replace('scss', 'css'))
        console.log(file.path.replace(file.name, '').replace('scss', 'css'))
        cb();
    });
}

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src(sassFiles)
    .pipe(debug({title: 'test:', minimal: false}))
    .pipe(parsePath())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    //.pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    //.pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
        //return file.path.replace('scss', 'css');
        //return path.relative(path.join(file.cwd, file.base), file.path).replace('scss', 'css');
    //}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
        console.log(file.base);
        return file.base;
    }));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function(){
  gulp.watch(sassFiles, ['sass']); 
})
```

Thanks for any help.

Ps.: In any case it was needed, I am running on Debian Jessie x64.

Pps.: I did google and read quite a lot of stackoverflow threads, but none of them had a solution to my problem (well, if it had, it didn't work for me).

Comment: U sure that you want separate .css files and not all scss files compiled into one css? And did I understand it right? You have for example 2 App Folders where SCSS Files are in one Folder and CSS in another. And now you want to simply compile them? Why you dont execute this gulp task in every app folder? Would be easier for the first step

Comment: @MarkusG. Yes I am sure. We do not include all files on every page, and we have our custom minifier that also combines all files used on specific page (module) into one file. There are more than 2 app folders, and not all of them have any frontend (so no scss files at all). I need it to be flexible, so if we add new app folder it would auto compile them. Thing is, my boss loves editing files live on the server, so i need something that will autocompile scss file and save it as css if he decides to play with my sass automagically without me even having to know he did anything...

Comment: Regarding multiple css files, you're way overthinking this. Having a bundle for each page kills optimization as you're forcing the user to re-download the same css from a slightly different bundle. Instead, you should have like a third-party bundle (bootstrap, plugins, etc.) and a bundle with your style. That way, browser caching will load the 2 files and then never have to download them again. After that, the compilation flow is a joke!

Comment: @EmileBergeron I forgot to add, I am not able to change the folder structure. I am not in charge of it and I never will be. I am trying to bring some new technologies to our company. Believe me, you do not want to see our workflow. Thats why I need exactly what I am asking for. If it wont be possible, then this company will probably never even switch to SASS. Ps.: Our minifier works in a simple way, you either tell it to minify file and combine it to a sitewide css, combine it to a css file with custom name or just minify the file without combining. It doesnt force you to download 100css files

Answer (score 0):

This is working.  It handles your rogueSASS files correctly and creates a css folder where you want it with the css files in there.

**IMPORTANT** : The gulp.src files are relative to where your gulpfile.js is located.  For this code I have it in the HTML folder - at the same level as the app_xxx folders.  If you put it somewhere else you will have to modify the sassFiles and rogueSassFiles declarations.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

// flatten can be useful to solve tricky long directory changes
// var flatten = require("gulp-flatten");

var rename = require("gulp-rename");
// var using = require("gulp-using");


const sassFiles = './**/styles/scss/*.scss';
const rogueSassFiles = ['./**/*.scss', '!./**/styles/**'];


gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'rogueSASS'], function () {
  gulp.watch( sassFiles, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch( rogueSassFiles, ['rogueSASS']);
})

gulp.task('sass', function () {

  return gulp.src(sassFiles)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))

       // remove the "scss" folder name from the end of the directory list

    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
       var temp = path.dirname.slice(0, -4);
       path.dirname = temp + "css";
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
})


gulp.task('rogueSASS', function () {

  return gulp.src(rogueSassFiles)
      //   gulp-using shows which files are getting through gulp.src !!
      //  .pipe(using())
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
})
```

These could be made into one task.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but I already tried similar things and it doesn't work like it should. Instead of creating the file in a folder relative to src, it creates the folder specified in dest it in root and that folder contains whole path in src but with compiled css file inside. So from `www/html/app_abc/styles/scss/layout.scss` it creates `www/html/css/app_abc/styles/scss/layout.css` IDK why it doesn't work, but but I couldn't find anything on google that would help me, so I did post here... Also, the partials ignoring was me trying to solve a bug that in the end was unrelated.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB I changed the code quite a bit.  It turns out it is relatively easy to accomplish your goal.